# API library based with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I've been thinking lately, I have this Spring-based web application which provides Rest API, it heavily uses `@Autowired`, `@Service` and `@Controller` annotations.

However, unlike a regular Java `Servlet` I am not sure how my application can be used with other project just like a regular servlet:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.Rest</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I am concerned mostly in the configuration files (like context.xml etc) used by the Spring app that I want to make a library of. Since the DAO class beans are defined in the xml, if I package the app as library, will it not conflict when the library is included in a Spring project?

Is this even possible? If so, how should the application be structured? I mean right now my Spring API project is based in a `WAR` structure.